# Refresh div after window resize

Tags: jquery, css, resize, refresh

im building responsive layout site and eveything is going great except one plugin.
Plugin is ulslide (lightweight gallery)

```
width of parent is:    
width:calc(100% - 330px);

width of div where plugin is:
width:100%;

-330px = panel on the right side
```

Everything is scalling great except this one div - it's scaling but after site refresh...
Is possible to refresh via jquery div after window size and orientation change ?
If not is it possible to change width of this object "in fly" when the window size change ?

I searched for similar thing but all answers was about whole site refresh which i dont want to use.

I could use:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: XXXpx){
}
```

But that's going to be the last thing i want.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can execute any code you want when the resize event is triggered using this piece of code:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {

});
```

In the function content you can play with your div width doing something like that:

```
$('#yourDivID').width(100);
```

Comment: Unfortunately window resize not working.
I need something that refresh div after window resize.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
     your function
});
```

For detail:
https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: $(window).resize(function() {
    var bodywidth = $(document).width();
    $("#div").width(bodywidth - 340);
});


Not working